# Upload an image in wordpress on a local server

Tags: wordpress

I am making my first steps coding and I have wordpress installed on my computer on a local XAMPP server. I try to add an image directly in a page from the wp admin but it's not possible and it shows me this error :

```
Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2016/03. Is its parent directory writable by the server?
```

Do you know why it happens? I create manually the directory wp-content/uploads/2016/03 and its still happening.

Comment: Have you checked if the permissions on your wp-content/uploads folder allows for writing files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create folder with name "uploads" in wp-content folder and set this folder permission 777

Hope it will work
Thanks

Comment: Is there a way to change a folder permission in Mac without using the comand line?

Answer (score 0):

Try to manually update/change the uploads directory instead of defaults:

1. Log into your WordPress admin dashboard.
2. Go to Media Settings menu *(Settings -> Media)*.
3. Enter `wp-content/uploads` in the *“Store uploads in this folder”* text
   box.
4. Save the changes by hitting the *“Save Changes”* button and you are
   done.

[image]

*Note:* if you don't have this option in your wordpress version,  you need to edit the `wp-config.php` file located in the root directory of your WordPress installation.

```
define( 'UPLOADS', 'wp-content/'.'uploads' );
```

also you can change the name of `uploads` folder as you want.

***UPDATE 1:***

Try adding the following to the top of your .htaccess file **(before *# BEGIN WordPress* line)**:

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
<Files async-upload.php>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</Files>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: It seems that we don't have the same admin dashboard panel. The only options that I have in settings/media are thumbnail size, medium size and large size

Comment: @ValentinVerdegales check my answer updates. _i hope it works :)_

Comment: where is that file? I don't have it

Comment: The _.htaccess_ file for WP should be in the folder where your WP install is - in the _root_ if WP is there, in a _subfolder_ if WP is installed in a subfolder. If you do not already have a _.htaccess_ file, create one. Refer to [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) -> _Creating and editing (.htaccess)_